# HTML base tag issue in IE8 with no sheme/protocol

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8, radix

I'm using TYPO3 for a website. TYPO3 includes a `<base href="" />` tag on every page

Now I have pages with and without SSL, So it would be nice to use a base tag with a now shema url

`<base href="//example.org" />` instead of `<base href="http://example.org" >`

Alas, the IE8 will not load my CSS and JS anymore. Is there a workaround other then reassigning the scheme?

Comment: You can use php to get the page scheme and than add it to all links...

Comment: @DanBarzilay: Sorry, it is absolutely not a TYPO3 way and it should be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [TypoScript conditions](http://typo3.org/documentation/document-library/core-documentation/doc_core_tsref/4.7.0/view/1/4/) to set proper `baseURL`

If for an example your HTTPS tree is placed in page with UID = 123 (and below) use:

```
config.baseURL = http://domain.tld/

[PIDinRootline = 123]
  config.baseURL = https://domain.tld/
[end]
```

In this way you can be sure that every browser which understands 'full' `base` tag will be working correctly.

Comment: It's not the thing, that I don't know how to manage it in Typo3. It's Typo3 that causes the issue because it uses `<base>` in the first place. But I wanted to know a way to make it work in IE8 more generally

Comment: Either way: If I choose conditions in this way it would be not good for the cache systems. I'd rather put an extra template on the pages with the uid